# Autofill Password & iCloud Security Password Emptied/Reset Password TextField

Tags: security, passwords, icloud, autofill

we are experiencing this same problem recently and could not come up with a solution. Basically the problem is that when **autofill password** is enabled and the same for the option in the preference to save the **security password** via **iCloud** we have the same problem posted by the OP in this thread:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716589?login=true&page=1#744911022

After filling the **password** field when we move to our **confirm password** field, the iOS system shows the same **action sheet** attached from the OP of that thread (**String password** or **Other Options**) and if we choose the **Other Options action** and then **Choose My Own Password** both field (Password & Confirm Password) will be emptied.

Is this a normal behavior and we as engineers have the responsability to cache the **password** typed by the user when dealing with **iCloud security password** & **autofill password** preferences options or is this a strange behavior?

Thank you everyone for the time, if you have any further question don't esitate to ask

We have already tried the suggestions provided in the thread linked above but nothing seems to work

Comment: I would like to add that the current solution we have found is to disable the secureTextEntry of the textfield but this could not be considered a solution